# Accessing values of a dictionary in a list using lambda

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I'm a newbie to python. I've multiple dictionaries inside a list and I want to do some analysis based on values. The reason I'm using lambda is because the function is not always expected. I'm just showing 2 dictionaries for reference, but the output gives me multiple dictionaries at times.

```
statistics = [{"ip_dst": "10.0.0.1", "ip_proto": "icmp", "ip_src": "10.0.0.3",
               "bytes": 1380, "port_dst": 0, "packets": 30, "port_src": 0},
              {"ip_dst": "10.0.0.3", "ip_proto": "icmp", "ip_src": "10.0.0.1",
               "bytes": 1564, "port_dst": 0, "packets": 34, "port_src": 0}]

packets = filter(lambda x: x[0]["packets"], statistics)
ip_src = filter(lambda x: x[0]["ip_src"], statistics)
ip_proto = filter(lambda x: x[0]["ip_proto"], statistics)
```

When I'm using a `print` statement, it's giving me a Key Error: 0. I understand that the value of packets is an integer and for ip_src/ip_proto, the value is a string.

How to access these values using lambdas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to extract the packets as a separate list of items then you wouldn't use filter. Filter will just reduce the number of dictionaries in a new list. You could use a list comprehension,

```
packets = [x['packets'] for x in statistics]
print(packets)
# [30, 34]
```

This creates a list of the `x['packets']` values in statistics.

The same for the other two sets of values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `[0]`.

When using `filter(lambda x: ...)`, `x` is the element in the iterable. 
Since you have a list of dictionaries, `x` will be the dictionary itself.

Your code should be:

```
statistics = [{"ip_dst": "10.0.0.1", "ip_proto": "icmp", "ip_src": "10.0.0.3", "bytes": 1380, "port_dst": 0, "packets": 30, "port_src": 0}, {"ip_dst": "10.0.0.3", "ip_proto": "icmp", "ip_src": "10.0.0.1", "bytes": 1564, "port_dst": 0, "packets": 34, "port_src": 0}]


packets = filter(lambda x: x["packets"], statistics)
ip_src = filter(lambda x: x["ip_src"], statistics)
ip_proto = filter(lambda x: x["ip_proto"], statistics)
```

Comment: When I'm printing "print packets", instead of giving me the value for packets only. The output is the whole list.
Same for ip_src and ip_proto.

Comment: Then use Andy G's answer. `filter` doesn't do what you think it does: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 0):

The filter function returns the original list without the elements where the lambda evaluates to false. So, if you did that correctly, you'd get all the elements anyways because a non-empty string or value other than 0 is considered to be True in Python.

If you'd like to get just those values of the keys, you need list comprehension.

```
packets = list(x["packets"] for x in statistics)
```